# Autopopulating userform with vlookup function

Tags: excel, database, vba, vlookup, userform

I have set up a userform with an ID number at the top and below are list of boxes that match the rest of the database. When the ID number is selected I would like all the other boxes in the userform to be filled e.g. using a vlookup. Below is the current formula but isn't working as I get the error:

> `Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.`

Any idea why?

Below is current code

```vb
Dim SLNo As Integer

SLNo = cmbdid.Value

Me.TextSendCode.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("EditForm").Range("B10:K13"), 2, 0)

Me.TextReceiveCode.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("EditForm").Range("B10:K13"), 3, 0)

Me.TextEntity.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("EditForm").Range("B10:K13"), 4, 0)

Me.TextAccNumber.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLNo, Sheets("EditForm").Range("B10:K13"), 5, 0)
```

`cmbdid` is the ID number text box name, `B10:k13` is database table

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: `Range("B10:K3"), ` is this correct?

Comment: `B3:k13 is database table` However, you have put `B10:K13` and `B10:K3` in the Range object. Could you correct the reference and check?

Comment: Why does one line not have a space between `Edit` and `Form`? Do you have two sheets, one named "EditForm" and one named "Edit Form"?

Comment: Correction above B10:K13 is the database table without the headers. No issue when I input the code however when I run and put a number in cmbdid box (ID number) to lookup against the ID number in the database (B10:B13) the error Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: @Marcos123, did you check last BigBen comment out?

Comment: @DisplayName yes the worksheet name is EditForm, edited above and ran with it and the same error appears: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.

Comment: If `Sheets("EditForm")` is in this workbook, then I'd propose using the worksheet codename to avoid typos, misspellings.